# Howto rephrase this INNER JOIN to be faster? I only need one row!

Tags: sqlite

Folks, help me out please.

I'm using SQLite (v3.35.5), and I have a fairly big table (with 800k rows).

I need to join this table to itself, for a special purpose.

Here is the table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_data (`id` INTEGER, `value` INTEGER, `result` INTEGER, `d0` INTEGER, `d1` INTEGER, `d2` INTEGER);
```

Task is easy: I need to find the *first row with d1=2* (ordered by *id asc*) after each row with *result=1*.

So let's see this sample data:

[image]

**result=1** happens at `id=1` and `id=4`.

So I'm gonna need this as my query's result:

[image]

This is perfect, as first **d1=2** rows after **result=1** rows are correct.

However, I'm reaching this with this query:

```
WITH
d1is2afterresultis1 AS (
  SELECT
    t0.*,
    t1.id
  FROM
    tbl_data t0
    
  INNER JOIN
    tbl_data t1 ON t1.id > t0.id AND t1.d1 = 2
    
  WHERE
    t0.result=1
    
  GROUP BY
    t0.id
)
SELECT
* 
FROM
d1is2afterresultis1
```

I need to keep the *CTE* (this is part of a larger query).

My problem is that in spite I have that *GROUP BY* statement, it takes way too much time if I run it on my 800k rows table (measured in minutes!).

And since I only need one row, I'm wondering how could I optimize this?

Here is the playground: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=5dcfb7621d9b11a71c2184323a3f456f

I know I can use a simple sub-query with `LIMIT 1`. It can give the desired result.

But how should I use it, if I need more columns, and not just one?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=373e2c18f82d047de30edaee75243f79) gives you some idea

Comment: Exactly, I have realized the solution 5mins after writing this question. Thank you. To have some points for you, please post it as solution and I'll happily accept it.

Comment: How would you modify this, if I need more columns from that particular row? Multiple subqueries?

Comment: Because there is no answer yet, you can edit your question and add to it the new requirements, or you can add a new question with a reference to this one.  In any case, you should add the desired result.